# Question about functionality of grabbing a brands coupons

Tags: coupon

I am looking for suggestions from the community on how coupon sites like Couponfollow, RetailMeNot, etc get their data. One thought I had was they manually go to websites and subscribe to emails and then have a script that parses out any coupon and % of listed in a marketing email. However, I have seen websites like the above also posting non-public coupon codes.

So wondering if they found a way to access /get coupons directly from brands ecommerce platforms?